# Античит в android приложении

Tags: android, android-studio

Можно ли защитить оперативные данные приложения от взлома? То есть я пишу игру в Android Studio и в игре есть такой параметр как деньги (монеты, коины) и при использовании стороннего софта (GameKiller, Game Guardian и др.) можно взломать игру, подменив значение. Всем давно известно, что любая логика, если она находится на клиенте, рано или поздно будет взломана, поэтому я не рассуждаю о 100% защите, хотя бы усложнить эту задачу читерам.

Как один из вариантов можно подменять значение, вместо обычного `Float` создать свой класс, который при инициализации будет прибавлять рандомный `offset`, а если нужно получить значение, то делаем `public float getValue() { return mFloat - mOffset; }`

Может быть у кого-нибудь есть еще идеи по этому поводу (помимо загрузки логики на сервер)?

Comment: При хранении параметров в локальном storage... Как вариант: записать значение в строку, и хранить base64 этой строки.   Конечно и это можно обойти, если знать что там base64. На случай если кто-то изменит значение base64 можно еще хранить md5 hash параметра. Когда будет запрос к локальному хранилищу - посчитать значение md5 сохраненного параметра и сравнить его с md5 из хранилища. Если они не совпали, то юзер хотел считерить, восстановить действительное значение параметра не удасться, останется только наказать читера обнулив параметр.

Comment: Знакомый пытался защитить. Он просто зашифровал значения. Правда, с помощью unity-приблуды какой-то он еще и в памяти их припрятал так, что их не найти гг, не гк и т.д. Но главная проблема в том, что я могу открыть исходники, отредактировать функцию и наслаждаться. Я думаю, что именно код надо защищать в таком случае...

Comment: Если вы про декомпиляцию, то я использую ProGuard, а кода в игре немало, на деобфускацию у злоумышленников уйдет куча времени, поэтому, это не такая критическая проблема (имхо). На unity есть своеобразный античит за 130$, но на XDA есть тема, как от него избавиться.

Comment: @NikitaG. Ну обфускация это хорошо... Главное, чтобы perfomance не задевало. Советовал бы Stringer, топ тема, правда платный. Я сейчас у друга спрошу, как он прятал значения от гг.

Comment: Ну на решетке (под Unity на Android) он делал так:http://imgur.com/a/8qAqQ . PlayerPrefs - это обычные конфиги. Гг такое не видит.

Comment: (если ты начинающий разработчик игр)
Не мучай себя Jav(ой) и Android Studio. Тем более android studio больше специализируется под программы и игры на ней писать тяжко и муторно(имхо). Попробуй начать с Unity и C#, знаний Jav(ы) (базового) тебе хватит по горло, что бы за 2-3 дня разобраться с c#.
На Unity как раз защиту легко сделать (ну что бы усложнить взлом). Как раз первые проекты по закидываешь в маркет, а там уже освоишь клиент-серваки и не будешь об защите париться.

Comment: Зато PlayerPrefs легко взламывается на windows, но это совсем другая история. Да и к тому же я не пишу под unity сейчас :)

Comment: Ложное значение как один из вариантов. Если "хакер" меняет значение - todo